# Oracle NoSQL Database - Developing with it

Tags: java, c++, sql, oracle, oracle-nosql

I recently came in touch with the [Oracle NoSQL Database](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/nosqldb/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen). 
It appears as though one can connect to it only from Java ([more info here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/NOSQL/html/index.html)). Is it possible to work with this DB from other languages, like say: Python, Erlang, C++ e.t.c. ? OR its like the usual `11G` database which can be talked to via ODBC, Oracle Drivers e.t.c. ? 
Anyone with more info on this, i will appreciate so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this: https://github.com/yeysus/14a

I don't know the current developement status though, and the support of interaction might be limited, as Java is the main language to go with this DB.

If it's about NoSQL without Java and you have the choice, something like MongoDB oder CouchDB might be the better choice!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, old post. But, I will still go ahead and respond, just in case if there are other folks facing similar issues.

Oracle NoSQL does has drivers for python, javascript. Please see below links :

Python : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nosqldb
JavaScript : https://www.npmjs.com/package/nosqldb-oraclejs